# Extract string from column sql?

Tags: sql-server-express

So I have this column called MESSAGE on my LOGS Table that has every line starting like this (well, at least they all start with the word Percentage):

```
Percentage|15/25|1%*1569ms#0ms*C:\Snapshot\Snapshot_15.jpg
```

I need to select the string

```
1569ms
```

in this case. They always come between * and #.
How can I do this?

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MESSAGE, , ) as Duration FROM LOGS
```

Comment: TBH, I'd just do this operation in the application layer rather than the database layer.

Comment: Yeah, I know it could be better. But in this case I really need a query in my db

Comment: What specific type of SQL?  That very likely will affect the answer.  EDIT: Please add the appropriate tag for the SQL type to the question.

Comment: If all of your records are formatted like that, I'd definitely recommend cleaning that up and getting things into their own columns. If you can't do that, there are a few possible cheats - wrapping a view around it with all the substring/charindex nonsense so you can query it more easily - or go the opposite route: fix the data, dump it into a table with a different name, drop this table, and make an updatable view with the same name/columns as this table, where the insert/update trigger breaks up the data into the good columns in your actual table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(MESSAGE,
            CHARINDEX('*',message)+1,
            CHARINDEX('#',message)-CHARINDEX('*',message)-1) as Duration 
FROM LOGS
```

Answer (score 1):

Use below mentioned SQL query to fetch the output specified by you:

```
SELECT DISTINCT CASE 
        WHEN NAME IS NOT NULL
            AND len(NAME) > 40
            AND (CHARINDEX('#0ms', NAME) - CHARINDEX('|1%*', NAME) - 4) > 0
            THEN SUBSTRING(NAME, CHARINDEX('|1%*', NAME) + 4, (CHARINDEX('#0ms', NAME) - CHARINDEX('|1%*', NAME) - 4))
        ELSE ''
        END
FROM dbo.Table_1
```

We have in-build function in SQL to break the string(SUBSTRING()) or to fetch the index of any character with in a string(CHARINDEX), so by using both function we can easily find out the exact syntax as per our requirement.

Comment: It might be the possibility that you have some other patterned data in the same column So in that case it is breaking the statement. I have modified my answer, now you can take the latest script from their.