# SQL - String Manipulation

Tags: sql-server, ssrs-2017

**Context:** 
I have a view in SQL Server that tracks parameters a user inputs when they run an SSRS report (ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog). About 50 report parameters are saved as a string in a single column with ntext datatype. I would like to break this single column up into multiple columns for each parameter.

**Details:** 
I query the report parameters like this:

```
SELECT ReportID, [Parameters]
FROM ReportServer.dbo.ExecutionLog
WHERE ReportID in (N'redacted')
and [Status] in (N'rsSuccess')
ORDER BY TimeEnd DESC
```

And here's a small subset of what the results look like:

`alpha=123&bravo=9%2C33%2C76%2C23&charlie=91&delta=29&echo=11%2F2%2F2018%2012%3A00%3A00%20AM&foxtrot=11%2F1%2F2030%2012%3A00%3A00%20AM`

**Quesitons:**

**How can I get the results to look like this:**

[image]

**SQL Server 2017 is Python friendly. Is Python a better language to use in this scenario just for parsing purposes?**

I've seen similar topics posted [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/string-functions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4793720/how-to-extract-substring-in-sql-server) & [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37816488/extract-string-from-column-sql). The parameters are dynamic so parsing via SQL string functions that involve counting characters doesn't apply. This question is relevant to more people than just me because there's a large population of people using SSRS. Tracking & formatting parameters in a more digestible way is valuable for all users of SSRS.

Comment: You might also consider not using the ntext datatype anymore. It has been deprecated for almost 15 years now. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/ntext-text-and-image-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a way using the built in `STRING_SPLIT`. I'm just not sure what the logic is for the stuff AFTER the date, so I would discarded it but I left it for you to decide.

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=c3a9e2a1237125a913005a9fe1233df1)

```
declare @table table (ReportID int identity(1,1),  [Parameters] varchar(8000))
insert into @table
values
('alpha=123&bravo=9%2C33%2C76%2C23&charlie=91&delta=29&echo=11%2F2%2F2018%2012%3A00%3A00%20AM&foxtrot=11%2F1%2F2030%2012%3A00%3A00%20AM')
,('alpha=457893&bravo=9%2C33%2C76%2C23&charlie=91&delta=29&echo=11%2F2%2F2018%2012%3A00%3A00%20AM&foxtrot=11%2F1%2F2030%2012%3A00%3A00%20AM')

select 
    ReportID
    ,[Parameters]
    ,alpha = max(iif(value like 'alpha%',substring(value,charindex('=',value) + 1,99),null))
    ,bravo = max(iif(value like 'bravo%',substring(value,charindex('=',value) + 1,99),null))
    ,charlie = max(iif(value like 'charlie%',substring(value,charindex('=',value) + 1,99),null))
    ,delta = max(iif(value like 'delta%',substring(value,charindex('=',value) + 1,99),null))
    ,echo = max(iif(value like 'echo%',substring(value,charindex('=',value) + 1,99),null))
    ,foxtrot = max(iif(value like 'foxtrot%',substring(value,charindex('=',value) + 1,99),null))
from @table
cross apply string_split(replace(replace([Parameters],'%2C',','),'%2F','/'),'&')
group by ReportID, [Parameters]
```

Or, if they aren't static you can use a dynamic pivot. It'll take some massaging to get your columns in the correct order.

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=b51873a8095fe0c896facd83457de793)

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX);

SET @cols = STUFF((SELECT distinct ',' + QUOTENAME(substring([value],0,charindex('=',[value]))) 
                from myTable
                cross apply string_split(replace(replace([Parameters],'%2C',','),'%2F','/'),'&')
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')


select @cols

set @query = 'SELECT ReportID, ' + @cols + ' from 
            (
                select ReportID
                    , ColName = substring([value],0,charindex(''='',[value]))
                    , ColVal = substring([value],charindex(''='',[value]) + 1,99)
                from myTable
                cross apply string_split(replace(replace([Parameters],''%2C'','',''),''%2F'',''/''),''&'')
           ) x
            pivot 
            (
                 max(ColVal)
                for ColName in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

Comment: This answer assumes the column names are known in advance.   Based on the question, I assume they are not, and are dynamically derived from the data.

Comment: So the pivot would be a single row then, since multiple reports can have different parameter names which wouldn't fit into a single result set aside from being in a single line

Comment: True, I do assume the pivot is a single row, since that was in the desired result image.   However, my assumption is no more valid than yours.   Just pointing it out.

Comment: The column names in the report are static & are known in advance. It's the parameters the user inputs that are changing every time the report is ran.thanks so much @scsimon

Comment: Well if you need the dynamic way, see my edit. That'd cover what @TabAlleman was talking about

Comment: No problem @emalcolmb

Answer (score 0):

Split the string on the ampersand character.

Further split each row into two columns on the equals character.

In the second column, replace `%2C` with the comma character, and `%2F` with the forward-slash character, and so on with any other replacements as needed.

Use a dynamic-pivot to query the above in the format that you want.

Comment: thanks tab alleman. are you suggesting the stuff & string split functions? could you give an example or link to a source?

Comment: There are many string-split functions out there, and I think 2017 has a built-in one.   Just google and you will find examples.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a method that starts with a lot of replaces.
To url-decode the string and transform it into an XML type.

Then it uses the XML functions to get the values for the columns.

Example snippet:

```
declare @Table table ([Parameters] varchar(200));

insert into @Table ([Parameters]) values
('alpha=123&bravo=9%2C33%2C76%2C23&charlie=91&delta=29&echo=11%2F2%2F2018%2012%3A00%3A00%20AM&foxtrot=11%2F1%2F2030%2012%3A00%3A00%20AM');

select 
x.query('/x[key="alpha"]/val').value('.', 'int') as alpha,
x.query('/x[key="bravo"]/val').value('.', 'varchar(30)') as bravo,
x.query('/x[key="charlie"]/val').value('.', 'varchar(30)') as charlie,
x.query('/x[key="delta"]/val').value('.', 'varchar(30)') as delta,
convert(date, x.query('/x[key="echo"]/val').value('.', 'varchar(30)'), 103)as echo,
convert(date, x.query('/x[key="foxtrot"]/val').value('.', 'varchar(30)'), 103) as foxtrot
from @Table
cross apply (select cast('<x><key>'+ 
  replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(
    replace([Parameters], 
       '%2C',','), 
       '%2F','/'), 
       '%20',' '), 
       '%3A',':'),
       '=','</key><val>'), 
       '&','</val></x><x><key>') 
     +'</val></x>' as XML) as x) ca
```

Test on *db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2014&fiddle=a9afdcd850ffc024a93f61fa9adf9e59)*